# Numerical Solution to system of balance law with ode system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, runge-kutta-methods

My question is realted to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2315431/numerical-solution-to-system-of-odes-coupled-to-a-pde), but different.

### Governing equations

I need to simulate the following system, i.e. vector balance law + ode,
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{u}}{\partial t} + \dfrac{\partial\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{u})}{\partial x} = \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{u},a,b), \\
\dfrac{da}{dx} = q_1(\mathbf{u},a,b), \\
\dfrac{db}{dx} = q_2(\mathbf{u},a,b). \\
\end{array}
$$
With open boundary conditions (BC) and under some initial conditions (IC).

### Questions

**Q1.**
Suppose, I would like to apply method of lines (MOL) and Runge-Kutta (RK) method. Should I derive differential-algebraic system (DAE), shouldn't I?

**Q1.1** Is it possible to discretize initial system on a staggeded (leapfrog) grid by using MOL and RK tecnhiques?

**Q2.** How to simulate initial system in general?

Comment: What are _open_ boundary conditions?

Comment: @mattos, means Neumann boundary conditions for pde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By open boundary conditions, you maybe mean outflow boundary conditions, which are easy to implement (see e.g. the book by R.J. LeVeque, 2002).

**A1.** Yes.

**A2.** Yes, but there may be numerical issues such as a very restrictive stability condition, or numerical stiffness.

**A3.** You can actually follow the steps in the [linked post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2315431/numerical-solution-to-system-of-odes-coupled-to-a-pde) by introducing a small parameter $\epsilon$ such that
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{u}}{\partial t} + \dfrac{\partial\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{u})}{\partial x} = \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{u},a,b), \\
\epsilon\dfrac{\partial a}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\partial a}{\partial x} = q_1(\mathbf{u},a,b), \\
\epsilon\dfrac{\partial b}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\partial b}{\partial x} = q_2(\mathbf{u},a,b). \\
\end{array}
$$
which is a system of balance laws of the form ${\bf q}_t + {\bf \Phi}({\bf q})_x = {\bf R}({\bf q})$. Then, one can split the left-hand side (propagation part) from the right-hand side (relaxation part). For example, one can choose to link the small parameter to the time-step as $\epsilon = \alpha (\Delta t)^\beta$.

Comment: Thank you for the consistent answer. Concerning A3. Should I divide by $\epsilon$, shouldn't I? Seems that vector $\mathbf{q}$ is 
$$
\mathbf{q}=
\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{u}\\a\\b
\end{pmatrix},
$$ isn't it?

Comment: @OlegKravchenko yes, dividing by $\epsilon$, we can write a first-order system of balance laws for ${\bf q}=({\bf u},a,b)^T$ and ${\bf\Phi}({\bf q}) = ({\bf F}({\bf u}),a/\epsilon,b/\epsilon)^T$.